# How to create a route with dynamic count of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create a route with dynamic count of parameters in mvc project. That route should refer to the same controller action. For example

> /catalog/cars/
>   /catalog/cars/bmw
>   /catalog/cars/bmw/x1

should be handled by the same action.

How should route look? Or I need to create three route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write tree route just make parameters optional:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "YourRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{catalog}/{subcatalog}/{model}",
            defaults: new { 
               controller = "Home", 
               action = "Index", 
               catalog = UrlParameter.Optional, 
               subcatalog = UrlParameter.Optional, 
               model = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think my question was not quiet explained. I also need use extra parameters at the end of route... For example page parameter...

Answer (score 0):

This should work with the default route you get with a new MVC project or you can make a specific one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Cars",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{manufacturer}/{model}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Catalog", 
        action = "Cars", 
        manufacturer = UrlParameter.Optional,
        model = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You just need an action method with optional parameters:

```
public class Catalog : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Cars(string manufacturer = "", string model = "")
    {
        //snip
    }
}
```

Comment: and why you need default `string.Empty` value for parameters in controller?